# Get all columns within last month with a JPA query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My current Query counts all tickets sold for each event and lists each event with the most tickets desc. Now the problem is, that I need to also get all tickets within the last month and I simply can not get the needed result from the JPArepo Doc. only. 
The current query looks like this:

```
@Query("select t.event.id, count(t.id) from Ticket t where t.event.seat = True group by t.event.id order by count(id) desc")
```

I am thinking a where after the "True" and before the grouping needs to be implemented but I just dont know how. 
I would be really greatful if someone of you could manage to help me out!

Edit: Forgot to mention that the current event date is simply called "date", so to access it what needs to be done is simply t.event.date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to something like this:

```
@Query("select t.event.id, count(t.id) from Ticket t where t.event.seat = ?1 and t.event.date >= ?2  group by t.event.id order by count(t.id) desc")
List<?> getEventCount(Boolean seatTaken, Date eventDate);
```

I modified the query to have the seat be a boolean parameter (for reusability if you want to find seats that were not taken) and added in the `Date` parameter.

Then calculate the date a month back as such:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

And finally implement the new method:

```
List<?> results = repo.getEventCount(true, date);
```

To create a Service class in spring and put it all together try something like:

```
@Service
public class TicketService {

  @Autowired
  private TicketRepository repo;

  public List<?> getTicketEventCount() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    Date date = cal.getTime();

    List<?> results = repo.getEventCount(true, date);
    return results;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am really new to JPA. In order to actually implement your suggested implementation I would need to create an service class that implements the repository , right ? How exactly is this done with Spring?

Comment: Check out Spring JPA's documentation. Its lengthy (too much to really post here), but good source material to get you started

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories

Comment: I actually did! My problem though is, that all the examples are in the interface of a repository, My question is, is the a need to implement a new service only for those 3lines of code ? Or is there maybe a way to actually write it all in a single query without the need of those three calendar lines ?

Comment: You will need to calculate the "month ago" portion before you use it in your query, the other alternative is to write a stored procedure in your database that can do it. See my edit to show the service.